# Group by with include (inner join)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, iqueryable

I am querying a table resulting from two other tables in the image below.
In one category I can have several questions.

[image]

using this query did not have the result I expected:

```js
 var result = await _repository.GetQuestionCategory()
                 .Include(x => x.Category)
                 .Include(y => y.Question)
                 .Select(x => new QuestionCategoryViewModel
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     CategoryId = x.Category.Id,
                     CategoryName = x.Category.Name,
                     IsRequired = x.IsRequired,
                     QuestionId = x.Question.Id,
                     QuestionName = x.Question.Name,
                     Weigth = x.Weigth
                 }).GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How could I send a similar structure like this

{ categoryId, categoryName, IsRiquered, Weigth, questions: [ questionId: questionName: y]}

Mmodel Category and Question

```js
    public class QuestionCategory
    {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Question Question { get; set;}
  public Category Category { get; set;}
  public int QuestionId { get; set; }
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
  public int Weigth { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You will need to use `GroupBy`. Can you show the type of `QuestionCategory`? Specifically, what are `.Question` and `.Category`?

Comment: I am using, as code above. For this is bringing matrix group and without condition this structure : {categoryId, categoryName, IsRiquered, Weigth, questions: [{questionId: questionName: y}]

Comment: I edited this post with the model

Comment: Wrong model - needed `QuestionCategory` or definitions for the properties `y.Question` and `x.Category`, not their classes.

Comment: I Update my post

Comment: It seems your model is not normalized... you mix the `QuestionCategory` model with the `Question:Category` `m:n` mapping. At least your post suggests this, since you expect to get a result of multiple questions with same `Category` and `IsRequired, Weight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a GroupBy statement with most of its parameters. Note the inconsistent naming of the result properties is taken 1:1 from the question. You may want to create some explicit DTO type instead of creating the result as anonymous type.

```
IQueryable<QuestionCategory> questionCategories = new EnumerableQuery<QuestionCategory>(Enumerable.Empty<QuestionCategory>());

var result = questionCategories.GroupBy(
    // key selector
    qc => new
    {
        categoryId = qc.CategoryId,
        categoryName = qc.Category.Name,
        IsRiquered = qc.IsRequired,
        Weigth = qc.Weigth
    },
    // element selector
    qc => qc.Question,
    // result selector
    (k, v) => new
    {
        k.categoryId,
        k.categoryName,
        k.IsRiquered,
        k.Weigth,
        questions = v.Select(q => new {questionId = q.Id, questionName = q.Name}).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to group the repeated categories?

Comment: @EliemersonFonseca you have to decide on your desired result format. My answer targets the structure that you requested. If you need a different structure, you have to specify it.

Comment: Passed format is correct. But I need the category duplicates to be in the same body and not repeat like this

Comment: @EliemersonFonseca There shouldn't be any duplicates with the same category AND the same Weight / IsRequired value. Your format is not suitable to group the categories independently from the IsRequired and Weight values.